# Control the available locations in save-as dialog

Tags: configuration, dialog

We've created a basic Ubuntu image and the save-as dialog has, in addition to the default (Home, Desktop etc) locations, an additional location which is related to our code and shouldn't be there. See screenshot (taken from Firefox but not limited to Firefox).

How did the additional location get there and, more importantly, how do I remove it?

Apologies if I'm not using the correct lingo...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @pomsky, I'm not sure, this is an image that is dockerised I nobody used the file-browser before this happened. Do you know where on the file-system I would find bookmarks?

Comment: Is there a bookmarks file in `~/.config/gtk-3.0`?

Comment: @pomsky, nope, it's empty

Comment: @pomsky, `user-dirs.dirs` looks normal. I just figured it out... it's the cwd, oopsie

Answer (score 1):

Well that's embarrassing... The additional directory is the application's CWD (working directory).

Future people who stumble on to this question, additional avenues suggested by [@pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481) are `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and `~/.config/gtk-3.0`.